# Overlay a view on GLSurfaceView with transparent background

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

Is it possible to overlay a view (i.e. button, text, etc.) on a transparent GLSurfaceView. I know that the only way to have a GLSurfaceView with a transparent background is by doing something like this:

```
mSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

However, this will always make the GLSurfaceView on top of the window and I cannot draw anything on top of this it. So, I am wondering if there is any solution to this problem.

Comment: The GLSurfaceView's surface is on a separate layer from the View elements. You can place that surface above the View elements or below them, but not in between them. Use a TextureView if you need more flexibility.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you vey much fadden

Comment: Is it possible to use MediaPlayer with TextureView and also associated the SurfaceTexture with EGL surface. I am asking this because I keep getting an issue with eglCreateWindowSurface where it keeps saying that the surface is "already connected to another API" which is the MediaPlayer in my case!!

Comment: Surfaces are actually a queue of buffers with a producer-consumer relationship, and they can only have one producer. You can't send video to a surface and render on it at the same time, so you'd need to use two different TextureViews and overlay them.